# Read 0 and 1 text file as binary in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, binary, qt5

I want to read a text file that contains 0 and 1 as binary, consider this example:

textfile.txt:

```
001001100101
010100011100
100000110001
001111110101
100010110101
111010100100
011011000110
```

I want to read this stream of 0 and 1 as binary or read then convert it. If we consider first line "001001100101", I want to convert it to 613 decimal and then with bit field or something like that, I check every bit of every number that was read. Only way that can do is to read line by line and then parse to string after that check every splitted string with "1" or "0" and find real value. I think there is a simple way for this problem.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where did you get stuck?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If there are only 0 and 1 in your file,

you can use stl std::stoi(const string&  str, [size_t* idx], [int base])

```
    string bin_string = "001001100101";
    int number = stoi(bin_string, nullptr, 2);
```